# HTML 5 canvas drawing image not showing css

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, transparency

When I try to draw an image on a canvas with a pre-loaded image with css like:

```
img.style.backgroundColor="red";
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,100,100);
```

I find that the image is being drawn as it would appear without the css. Do HTML canvases support css? If not is there a way to overlay a png with transparency with a color only on the pixels that are not transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to overlay the image drawn on a canvas by analyzing each pixel of the drawn image and then overlaying a 1x1 rectangle with the desired color. Here is an example of how to do so:

```
function overlayColor(img,x,y,a,r,g,b,drawWidth,drawHeight){
    //create a canvas in memory and draw the image there to analyze it
    var tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
    tmpCanvas.width = drawWidth;
    tmpCanvas.height = drawHeight;
    context.drawImage(img,0,0,drawWidth,drawHeight);
    let pData = new Array();
    for (let i = 0; i < tmpCanvas.width; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < tmpCanvas.height; j++){
            if (context.getImageData(i, j, 1, 1).data[3] != 0){//if the pixel is not transparent then add the coordinates to the array
                pData.push([i,j]);
            }
        }
    }
    //then every pixel that wasn't transparent will be overlayed with a 1x1 rectangle of the inputted color 
    //drawn at the (x,y) origin which was also given by the user
    //this uses ctx, the context of the canvas visible to the user
    ctx.fillStyle="rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + a + ")";
    for (let i = 0; i < pData.length; i++){
        ctx.fillRect(x + pData[i][0],y + pData[i][1],1,1);
    }

}
```

Since the function takes an x and y value the image given by the user will be analyzed and overlayed only on pixels that are not transparent at the coordinate given by the user with the rgba value also given. I have found that this process can result in some lag but it could be overcome by saving the pData array and using the second half of the function to draw the array on screen again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify more about our requirement?

You can not set the background colour of an image which is going to draw directly from the canvas. if you altering a color, it will reflect in the source image.

You have to make it from the source element. If you want to fill the box size with some color, you could use `fillStyle` of the ctx before draw.

Comment: I have a png that I was trying to tint the color on using the css. So I couldn't use fillStyle because it would cover transparent space.

Comment: It wont tint the colour even if you add the background. For that you could do one workaround. Get the start position of the image, and add a rectangle with same height and width of the image. Set the opacity of the image to 30% or desired value before draw.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example here on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trycanvas_image) that will get you started on how to load the image and copy it into the canvas.  If you don't need the original image to be shown on the page then add 'style="display:none;"' to the img tag.  To tint the image have a look at globalAlpha in combination with a filled rect - something along these lines:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");

    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas do not render css no matter what css you use for image it will always render plain image unless you draw border or background by yourself